# Adding custom .DataLabels to an xlXYScatterSmooth chart, running into 255 character limit for msoChartFieldRange string

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

msoChartFieldRange requires a string including Sheet Name.

This string works: "(Averages!$F$9, Averages!$I$9, Averages!$L$9, Averages!$O$9, Averages!$R$9)"

This string doesn't: "(Averages!$F$9,$I$9,$L$9,$O$9,$R$9)", so just passing ColumnSelect(4).AddressLocal(True, True, , True) also doesn't work

Problem is when the string that works goes over 255 characters

Supposedly you can use a Range with msoChartFieldFormula as stated by MS here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.textrange2.insertchartfield, but I can't seem to get syntax correct to accept a Range.

Easiest answer is to figure out how to pass a Range, but I have not found anything on what the proper syntax is?

Any help is appreciated

Currently I use a function to split the Range and build it into the proper string:

```
NewString = SplitRangeAddress(ColumnSelect(4).AddressLocal(True, True, , True))

.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=" & NewString, 0 ' This works until it hits the 255 character limit

.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldFormula, ColumnSelect(4), 0 ' This doesn't work, gives a "The specified parameter has an invalid value" error.
```